# Configuring hibernate 4.2.1 in a maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, mssql-jdbc

I'm configuring Hibernate 4.2.1 in a maven project and I'm using MS SQL JDBC to connect to a SQL Server Database. When I run my class Test I get the following error:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver could not be loaded
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2293)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1758)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1798)
    at com.lbv.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:146)
    ... 15 more
```

I need your help friends.

Comment: It seems to me that you do not have an SQL driver (i.e. a dependency is missing)?

Comment: No, i have jdbc mssql dependency.

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.6.jre8-preview</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: When you get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" is a good idea to ensure that the proper .jar exists in the WEB-IF/lib folder of your deployment

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `<scope>test</scope>` from your dependency declaration. You aren't only using the driver for your tests, but also for your actual runtime use.

Specifying `<scope>test</scope>` will instruct Maven to only load the dependency when running your tests. You should also ask yourself if you really want to use a preview version, and not a officially released version (ie: 6.2.2.jre8).